# Ubuntu ffmpeg watermark position

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, watermark

so I have command:

```
ffmpeg -i prepared/video.mp4 -i units/video_watermark.png -filter_complex overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10 -codec:a copy moved/video_test.mp4
```

which should describe watermark position on bottom right but the watermark appears on the bottom center. what i'm doing wrong?

also I tried this command:

```
ffmpeg -i prepared/video.mp4 -vf "movie=units/video_watermark.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10 [out]" moved/output.mp4
```

but with it watermark was not added, video was corrupted becouse of response:

> [aac @ 0x3556540] The encoder 'aac' is experimental but experimental codecs are not enabled, add '-strict -2' if you want to use it.

where is the clue?

Comment: You should always include the complete console output from your command.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
ffmpeg –i inputvideo.avi -vf "movie=watermarklogo.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=(main_w-overlay_w-10)/2:(main_h-overlay_h-10)/2 [out]" outputvideo.flv
```

Credits to Github user [charlee](https://gist.github.com/charlee/4522801)

Comment: There is no need to use the `movie` source filter, and the additional baggage it requires, when you can just use `-filter_complex` instead as shown by the command in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your image may need to be re-sized. Otherwise your command is working fine. What I'm suggesting is as follows.

```
ffmpeg -i input_video -i input_image -filter_complex "
[1:v]scale=320:240[v1];
[0:v][v1]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10" -codec:a copy output_video
```

This will scale down your input image to 320x240 detentions which is smaller than the video and then overlay it.

To correct your second command you need to add `-strict experimental` or `-strict -2` before specifying the output file.

Hope this helps!